# Объект IAsyncResult не был возвращен соответствующим асинхронным методом данного класса

Tags: c#, сокеты

Из-за чего возникла ошибка?

Здравствуй ХешКод, решил написать чат где может подключатся много людей одновременно, когда люди подключаются на сервер добавляется запись

```
%username%, вошёл в систему
```

А когда уходит я пытаюсь добавить надпись что он покидает нас, но возникает ошибка... не знаю что делать. Вот код:

```
class Program
{
    private static Socket server, client;
    private static byte[] buffer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        writeData.writeInfo("Инициализация");
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 4000));
        server.Listen(0);
        writeData.writeInfo("Сервер запущен на: " + server.LocalEndPoint.ToString());

        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        buffer = new byte[1024];

        client = server.EndAccept(result);

        writeData.writeGood("Подключен новый пользователь: " + client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());

        client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);

        server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
    }

    private static void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int num = client.EndReceive(result);

        Array.Resize(ref buffer, num);

        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        if (text == "exit")
            writeData.writeBad("Клиент отключен: " + client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
    }
}
```

Код ошибки:

```
Объект IAsyncResult не был возвращен соответствующим асинхронным методом данного класса.
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? В какой строке? Если исключение, то какое?

Comment: Да исключение.

Comment: Посмотрите в исключении StackTrace, a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, но может быть вам поможет вот [эта статья](http://rajputyh.blogspot.de/2010/04/solve-exception-message-iasyncresult.html).

Вкратце: у вас race condition по значению переменной `client`: вы наверное её меняете до того, как вызвался соответствующий OnReceieve.

Попробуйте сделать как рекомендуется в статье. Или запомните socket в AsyncState:

```
// ... в OnAccept
client.BeginReceive(
    buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
    new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), client);

// ... в OnReceive
var client = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
```

Comment: Не то, чтобы даже race condition, просто один статический объект клиента используется, чтобы делать `EndReceive` всем другим.

Comment: Угу, вы фактически правы.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало, а скажите я немного не понял почему заменив слово null на client всё заработало? В чём была причина? И что делает эта строчка:

    var client = (Socket)result.AsyncState;

Comment: @Angus123: дело в том, что между вызовом `OnAccept` и вызовом `OnReceive` значение переменной `client` у вас менялось. А вам-то нужно "закончить" обработку с тем же сокетом, с которым вы её начинали! Поэтому мы засунули ссылку на правильный сокет в `AsyncState`, используя последний параметр `BeginReceive`, а потом её оттуда достали, и работаем с тем сокетом, с каким нужно.